# MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFU SED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Tags: javascript

My question is about mongo not connecting to the server?
and why is it saying that failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFU
SED 127.0.0.1:27017]

```
Here is my code:
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
mongoose = require("mongoose");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/BlogApp");
app.set("views engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Comment: Is Mongod server running? Check by reaching localhost:27017 in a browser.

Comment: try to `mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/BlogApp"); // 27017 is a standart port for mongo`

Answer (score 0):

Install mongodb on your machine, (If you're on a mac, run `brew install mongodb`), then open a new terminal, and run `mongod`, then relaunch your app

Comment: dude idk how but i found the problem to this insanity :D
This video helped me. even though i had mongodb installed and had it running in the background, i had to delete everything with mongoDB and then i redid everything; 
Ty for the help man. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWbMrx5rVBE&t=1659s

https://gist.github.com/JatinChauhan1998/0013763a275b114c8f9702e50dd730a4

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure MongoDB is properly installed on your computer
2. Turn on your MongoDB by typing `mongod` or `sudo mongod`

Then you need to verify if you connect successfully or if a connection error occurs by adding the following code.

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('We are connected to db!');
});
```

Your complete server code should look like this.

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

    // Use native promises
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/BlogApp");

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        // we're connected!
        console.log('We are connected to db!');
    });

    app.set("views engine", "ejs");
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
    });

   app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys. 
I ended up deleting the whole mongodb file and reinstall the whole thing, and now im good.